# google calendar api list doesn't return the right number of events

Tags: python, google-calendar-api

I am trying out the google calendar api quickstart https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/python and have noticed something weird.

```
  #this function returns 15 events by default. 
eventsResult = service.events().list(
    calendarId='primary', timeMin=t_now, timeMax=t_end, singleEvents=True,
    orderBy='startTime').execute()
```

But documentation says that MaxResult defaults to 250. 
Here you can see from the screenshot of my vscode that we are printed the 14th event. Since I started the counter at 0 that makes it 15 events. I have validates this with the debugger as well. eventsResult is a list with 15 items in it.

I don't understand why that is.

https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/list

[image]

Comment: Wild guess there are not 250 events in your calendar between timeMin and timeMax?

Comment: Correct, but I got for sure more than 15 events.